# Executor Service with void return type

Tags: runnable, executorservice, java-threads, callable

Here I want to call `n` threads and execute my function `padrDao.saveGuidanceDetails(sgd)` which is a DAO method performing insert operation and return a long value as shown in below code.

Im using Callable, but it asks me to return some value but I'm not familiar with threads to use `Runnable` for the same job. Can someone pls validate if code is right or any modifications to be done? I feel code is wrong since there is a return statement inside callable and that will take me outside the main method for the first task itself.

```
int totalThreadsNeeded=listForguidanceItems.size();     
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreadsNeeded);
List<Callable<Void>> runnableTasks = new ArrayList<>();
final PriceLineItemsResultExt response1=response;

for(final ProductLineItemResultExt item: listForguidanceItems)
{
    int counter=0;
    final SavedGuidanceDetailsDto sgd=list.get(counter);

    Callable<Void> task1 = new Callable() {
        public Void call() {
            if (sgd.hasGuidance())
            {
                if (response1.isSaveGuidance()) {
                    long guidanceDetailsId = padrDao.saveGuidanceDetails(sgd);
                    item.setGuidanceDetailsId(String.valueOf(guidanceDetailsId));
            } 
        }

        return null;
    }};

    counter++;
    runnableTasks.add(task1);
}

try {
    executor.invokeAll(runnableTasks);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.info("Thread fail exception  " + e);
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Pls suggest me modifications with the right code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To use Runnable you can simply replace these :

```
Callable<Void> task1 = new Callable() {
        public Void call() {
...
```

With

```
Runnable task1 = new Runnable {
  public void run() {
...
```

And with runnable you wouldn't have to return anything.

Of course you'd also need to modify you `runnableTasks` to be a `List<Runnable>` if tou still want to store these in a Collection (possibly not), and also change the way you submit them in the ExecutorService as :

```
executor.submit(your_Runnable_object)
```